# Joomla: comments for own component

Tags: joomla

I have written my own Jommla component for displaying particular information (for example car info: engine power, year and etc.).

Now I want to add a comments to my component.

Implementing comments by my own is too hard and it's not very safe.

Maybe someone had and experience integrating some existing joomla component for an own component?

**Update:**

Maybe I can copy-paste code of some existing joomla comments component in my own component?
Does somebody tried to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla specific implementation details and not programming as defined for StackOverflow, it would be better asked on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It's about programming and adaptation of existing code

Comment: It's not about programming, it's asking for advice on the choice of a comments extension. There are lots of choices and opinions, the Joomla forums are good for that and you could also ask on the Joomla site as @eppl said.  Most of the extension developers will have docs on how to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful with bespoke comments fields as they are open to spam attacks, unless carefully filtered and moderated.

If it would work for your needs, you are probably better building a simple module which embeds the Facebook or Disqus comment widgets onto your site, and then assigning it to your component pages.  These seem to be quite good at stopping most of the spam.

Comment: Yes, good solution. But these comments are not indexed by google.

Comment: Using disqus, you can sync your data and display it using their api, which will then be crawlable.  https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472125-data-synchronization